# 404 not found for virtual hosting url-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, virtualhost

I have a project `c:/xampp/testadmin`(laravel).I have created a virtual host for it.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/testadmin/public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    ServerName  mywebsitename.com
    ServerAlias mywebsitename.com
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/testadmin/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Actauly my `mywebsitename.com`
 is a sub domain url. Now everything is okay and project is up.but problem is that when i hit `mywebsitename.com/storage/app` i got an error
Object not found!

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the
>   URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> ```
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
> Error 404
> mywebsitename.com
> Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.0
> ```

but when i hit `localhost:8080/testadmin/storage/app` it's working.and now my App-URL is mywebsitename.com.how can i solve this isuue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think you change port 8080 to 80

Comment: Can you access `mywebsitename.com:8080/testadmin/storage/app` ?

Comment: @kuromoka nop i can't

Comment: can you show other parts of apache settings?